The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0. with Vue2
I realize similar questions have been asked before about this warning, but none of the proposed solutions have solved this issue for me, or been applicable in my scenario.
I have recently upgraded some packages in my Vue 2.7 project. Among other things, I have removed node-sass from the project in favor of just sass (dart-sass). I had to change from the @import syntax to @use and @forward. This is all fine now, but when running the project, I get dozens of these warnings:
The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

The proposed solutions I've found basically suggest to switch to modern-compiler in the Vite or equivalent config. However, my project uses webpack (4.47.0) and the main config file is vue.config.js. Here it is currently:
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  filenameHashing: false,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        // just path aliases
      }
    }
  }
};

Package versions that may be relevant here:
"vue": "^2.7.14",
"sass": "^1.83.0",
"sass-loader": "^10.5.2",
"webpack": "^4.47.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",

What exactly do I need to do in order to use this new "modern compiler" and avoid these errors?
Finally, as a last resort, if I wanted to just temporarily silence these warnings, how would I go about doing that? Thanks for any help.

This is a warning, you do not use the v2 of sass for now anyway, hence you should just ignore it. Try to migrate towards Vue3 + Vite ASAP to clean things out properly with the appropriate configuration.

From this page and given that doc, looks like the config is something like this
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              api: "modern-compiler",
              sassOptions: {
                // Your sass options
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};


The equivalent to the Vue config looks to be something like this
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  filenameHashing: false,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        // just path aliases
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                api: "modern-compiler",
                sassOptions: {
                  // Your sass options
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

configureWebpack will be in charge of extending the existing configuration.

This is for the default config when using webpack.config.js. The issue is translating this into something that Vue can use in vue.config.js. There is a way to include webpack config in chainWebpack within this vue config but everything I've tried has led me nowhere. I have went over the docs you linked in detail already.

@LiteralMetaphore updated my answer.

@LiteralMetaphore oh, I guess it's unfortunate then. Not sure about the exact syntax. But again, I would not be bothered too much by it and spend hours on it, especially for just a warning and if everything else works well.
